# Sorting blobs accordingly in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

How may I sort the blobs accordingly in opencv? I have all the blobs scattered over the image. I want it to be bottom right to be the first blob. Second blob to be bottom left from the 1st blob until top left the last blob. I need some suggestion on how to deal with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try something like this ..

```
bool sortBlobs(CBlob first, CBlob second) {

return first.x > second.x;
}


int main() {


  std::vector<CBlob> blobvector;

  CBlobResult blobs;

  // ...
  // find blobs here ...
  // ...

  for (int i = 0; i < blobs.GetNumBlobs(); i++ )
  {
    blobvector.push_back(blobs.GetBlob(i));
  }

  // now sort the vector
  std::sort(blobvector.begin(), blobvector.end(), sortBlobs);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: can you explain more what it does actually?

Comment: iiro. there is nothing in blobvector. how can i pass the detected blob to blobvector?

Comment: I enhanced my example now. Hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using cvBlobsLib in OpenCV?
For each detected blobs, you can get its region by

```
CvRect rect = blob->GetBoundingBox();
```

And then you can sort all of the blobs according the the rect.x.

Comment: Yes. i'm using cvBlobsLib. As you know if you are using the libs. it sort the blobs from the top most either it is at left or right. then it move downwards. instead if that, I want it be the way that i explained earlier. how can i sort according to your answer?